# Create a playlist via command line?

Tags: terminal, applescript, music, playlist

I have some rather complicated scripts that I use to create MP3 files which I use for improving my language skills.  Each session creates a new file in each of six languages, with text embedded in the lyrics tag.  It adds the files to existing albums named for the language.  Each track has the same title which changes each session.

Then in a **copy** of each new file, it changes title to (language), album to "Today’s Reading", and track number to the order I want to play/read.  These **replace** the previous set of "Today’s Reading."  (Album name misleading because I usually go several days on one set.)

It finally occurred to me that it would be simpler to make "Today’s Reading" a smart playlist where Title contains (new title).

So I have albums English, Spanish, Dutch, … each containing titles T1, T2, …, TN and album "Today’s Reading" containing titles English, Spanish, Dutch, …

I want to simplify it to have albums English, Spanish, Dutch, … each containing titles T1, T2, …, TN and playlist TN where title contains TN.

I could just remove all the code for "Today’s Reading" from the script and easily create the playlist manually but **is there a not too messy way to automate it with OSAscript or other shell command?** Or [with Xcode](https://superuser.com/questions/1491509/is-the-format-schema-of-the-apple-music-library-musicdb-used-in-macos-catalina) — I haven't used Swift before, but as a retired software engineer, I am hopefully not too old to learn it.

Actually, it doesn't have to be a "smart" playlist, since my script will know the titles of the tracks it should contain.  In fact, a "normal" playlist is better, since a smart playlist does not allow changing the order of tracks it lists.

---

**Update**: Seems I have not been perfectly clear.  What I’d like to automate (besides creating the playlist, which is easy to do) is importing it into the library.  I know of three ways to add it to the library, but all of them are manual action — `open`, double-click, or drag into Songs view.

Comment: A playlist ([M3U](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U)) is just a text file.  It only requires two things:  `#EXTM3U` at the top of the file and at least one entry `#EXTINF:` that indicates the the music file.  There’s lots more metadata that you can include, but it’s not necessary.  I don’t even believe this is an Apple related question as this would apply to music players across all platforms and is not necessary to utilize Xcode or any other dev tools.

Comment: A playlist in Music.app is embedded somewhere in the Music library, not in a separate text file.  A playlist that already exists can't be found by putting its name in Spotlight or in `find (dir) -exec grep -l (name) "{}"` even if (name) is also the title of a track in the playlist.

Comment: A smart search is the same as a spotlight search with keywords which can be done via command line using `mdfind`. The playlist is a text file.  This can be generated on your own.  You don’t need to utilize the “make smart playlist feature” embedded into Music to get what you’re looking for.

Comment: Where are the "textfile" playlists already created in Music.app, and why can't Spotlight/mdfind or `find` locate them?  Several online pages say they are stored in the Music library (but the three that I read were all written before the name change).  `find` in that directory could not find any file containing the name of an existing playlist nor the title of tracks in that playlist (which are also titles of MP3 files in the library)

Comment: It’s in the Music Library sqlite3 database.  Don’t overcomplicate things by trying to do this through music.  Create the M3U and import it into Music.  It will achieve the same results.

Comment: OK, so it isn't a text file, but I can create a text file and import it.  In that case, it would be convenient to automate the import in the same script that creates the text file.

Comment: I exported a playlist, edited it to include only file names, deleted the playlist in Music, and imported. Got what I wanted, and it can easily be automated. So perhaps you would like to change the comment(s) to an Answer? Include, if possible, how to import the playlist without having Music also start playing it.  (Experimentation reveals that all it needs are the filenames—the name of the created playlist is the title of one of the tracks, which are all have same title in my case.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you want, let me share you with my approach to play a playlist with command line

1. Generate a `songs.m3u` file with code. `.m3u` is a file for playlist, which looks like this

   ```
   #EXTM3U
   #EXTINF:Dusk Till Dawn
   file:///path/to/the/music/folder/ZAYN; Sia - Dusk Till Dawn.mp3
   #EXTINF:A Thousand Miles
   file:///path/to/the/music/folder/Vanessa Carlton - A Thousand Miles.mp3
   #EXTINF:Call Out My Name
   file:///path/to/the/music/folder/The Weeknd - Call Out My Name.mp3
   ```
2. Open it with `open` command, and it will start playing songs in the playlist

   ```sh
   open /path/to/file/songs.m3u -a /System/Applications/Music.app
   ```

Comment: Creating the playlist is easy enough.  But automating the import is not.  "open" or double-click or dragging into the songs view causes it to be added to the library.  any of those also starts playing it, which is not needed.  And all of them are manual processes, not automated.

Comment: @WGroleau I see, sorry that I can't help you with that